# Finding successive prime numbers with sum of previous terms as divisors

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers

How to approach reasoning about finding {p, q} where p, q are successive primes? I understand that proofs require intelligence, curiosity and that symmetry can be very useful. What are ways in this example to start playing around, to make discoveries and a mess? I hope the mathematical notation is correct:

$p \mod \left( \sum_\limits{\underset{i \text{ is prime}}{i<p}} i \right) = 0$

$q \mod \left( \sum_\limits{\underset{j \text{ is prime}}{j<q}} j \right) = 0$

I tried to create a Python function for finding pairs to a given limit, it only finds p=5:

````
from sympy import primerange, nextprime

def find_successive_prime_pairs(limit: int) -> None:
""" Finds successive pairs of prime numbers that have sums of lesser terms as divisors. """

for p in primerange(2, limit):
    sum_p = sum(primerange(2, p))   
    if sum_p != 0 and p % sum_p == 0:
        q = nextprime(p)
        sum_q = sum(primerange(2, q))
        if sum_q != 0 and q % sum_q == 0:
            print(f"Found pair: {p}, {q}")

# Example usage with a limit of 100
find_successive_prime_pairs(100)

```
````

Comment: Do we really have the conditions $i<pi$ and $j<qj$ ? Because they are always satisfied.

Comment: Is sum_p less than p, if not then the remainder can't be 0...

Comment: @Peter - that was a formatting issue. I've reformatted the summations to clarify.

Comment: Are you sure you have this problem correctly stated? The only way for a prime to be divisible by any number is when the divisor is either $1$ or the prime itself. As the sum cannot be $1$, this means it can only be equal to the prime. So the property is more easily stated as the sum of the lesser primes being equal to the prime. Further, there cannot *ever* be an adjacent pair $p, q$ of such primes, for if $S(n)$ is the sum of all primes below $n$, then $q = S(q) = S(p) + p = 2p$, meaning that $q$ is not prime. The opposite property that $p$ divides $S(p)$ seems far more interesting.

Comment: $\Sigma\equiv 0\pmod p$ makes more sense

Comment: The only prime that is divisible by (or equivalently, by the definition of prime, equal to) the sum of all the smaller primes is $5$. This is not very interesting. It would be more interesting to instead consider primes that divide the sum of the smaller primes.

Comment: Another prime that divides the sum of the smaller primes is $71$. Besides $5$ and $71$, there are no other such primes less than $10000$. Are $5$ and $71$ the only primes that divide the sum of the smaller primes?

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang $p=369119,\Sigma=5536785000$ is the only other $p<1000000$

Comment: [OEIS A007506](https://oeis.org/A007506) lists a couple more.

Comment: FYI - for the OP question of primes that are divisible by the sum of lower primes, Bertrand's Postulate (proved by Tchebychev in 1850) that there is always a prime between $n > 1$ and $2n$ proves Geoffrey Trang's statement that $5$ is the only example. For if $p < S(p)$ and $q$ is the next prime, then $q < 2p < p + S(p) = S(q)$.